# Can ssl handshake be established only with client certification validation instead of server certificate validation?

Tags: sockets, ssl, websocket, tcp

From my browser I want to communicate to localhost application using ssl. Here browser(which acts as client) will submit the certificate instead of localhost application(which acts as server). Can Ssl be established in this scenario? So finally it boils down to problem statement can a ssl communication be established by server validating the client certificate and client not validating the server certificate.

Comment: You can do this with various APIs, by kind of reversing the onus of proof, but not with a browser.

Comment: @user207421 How about doing it over websockets?

Comment: You need access to the underlying TLS/SSL socket and its API, whether Java or OpenSSL or whatever, so you can put it into 'server mode' before connecting, and you need the listening socket, or the accepted socket, to be in 'client mode' as well of course. I don't know whether you're in a position to accomplish any of that.

Answer (score 1):

The SSL/TLS implementation inside the browser do not support this scenario. A server certificate is always required by the browser with SSL/TLS in order to be sure that the browser is communicating with the expected server (as specified in the URL) and not some man in the middle. Apart from that it is not clear what you want to achieve with such a setup in the first place - maybe there is a better design for your unknown use case.